# How can I use `putImageData` with transparency?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am drawing a byte array of image data to a canvas with `putImageData`. The image data has some transparency, but when I draw multiple images to the canvas I don't see any overlap. In other words, I get this:

[image]

But I want this:

[image: Right]

I am clearly not understanding something about how alpha compositing works in Javascript/HTML, and I hope someone can help me with this problem. Thanks!

Sample code:

```js
const arr = new Uint8ClampedArray(4*100*100);

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 4) {
  arr[i + 0] = 255;
  arr[i + 1] = 0;
  arr[i + 2] = 0;
  arr[i + 3] = 100;
}

let imageData = new ImageData(arr, 100);

context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
context.putImageData(imageData, 50, 50);
```

Comment: Try using `context.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over";` before your `putImageData` calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `putImageData` (and to some extents `getImageData` too), is special: it won't care at all about the current context settings, that is, it will completely ignore the current context's transformation matrix, all its clipping regions, it will ignore the current context's `filter`, its `shadowColor`, its `globalAlpha`, etc. and back to our case, its `globalCompositeOperation`.
What it does is it sets the pixels on the canvas buffer at the untransformed coordinates to what is stored in the `ImageData` object.

So, yes, it will not composite your `ImageData` content with what was there, it will just replace it.

If you wish to draw your `ImageData` content as if it were a mere bitmap content, you can [convert it to an `ImageBitmap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/createImageBitmap) instead:

```js
(async() => {
  const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  const arr = new Uint8ClampedArray(4*100*100);

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 4) {
    arr[i + 0] = 255;
    arr[i + 1] = 0;
    arr[i + 2] = 0;
    arr[i + 3] = 100;
  }

  let imageData = new ImageData(arr, 100);
  const bmp = await createImageBitmap(imageData);

  context.drawImage(bmp, 0, 0);
  context.drawImage(bmp, 50, 50);
})();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Though beware this method is *somehow* async, so in an animation frame that might not be the best to use, and you may prefer falling back on using a second, offscreen, canvas, at the cost of a bigger memory impact.